# My code is running continuously in jupyter notebook and asterisk sign is remain on cell of jupyter notebook

Tags: conv-neural-network

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import keras 
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(r"C:\Users\ASUS\best_model_dataflair3.h5")
background = None
accumulated_weight = 0.5
ROI_top = 100
ROI_bottom = 300
ROI_right = 150
ROI_left = 350
def cal_accum_avg(frame, accumulated_weight):
    global background
    
    if background is None:
        background = frame.copy().astype("float")
        return None
    cv2.accumulateWeighted(frame, background, accumulated_weight)
def segment_hand(frame, threshold=25):
    global background
    
    diff = cv2.absdiff(background.astype("uint8"), frame)
    
    _ , thresholded = cv2.threshold(diff, threshold, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    
    #Fetching contours in the frame (These contours can be of hand or any other object in foreground) ...
    image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresholded.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # If length of contours list = 0, means we didn't get any contours...
    if len(contours) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        # The largest external contour should be the hand 
        hand_segment_max_cont = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
        
        # Returning the hand segment(max contour) and the thresholded image of hand...
        return (thresholded, hand_segment_max_cont)
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
num_frames = 0
while True:
    ret,frame = cam.read()

    # filpping the frame to prevent inverted image of captured frame...
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    frame_copy = frame.copy()

    # ROI from the frame
    roi = frame[ROI_top:ROI_bottom, ROI_right:ROI_left]
    gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray_frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_frame, (9, 9), 0)
    if num_frames < 70:
        
        cal_accum_avg(gray_frame, accumulated_weight)
        
        cv2.putText(frame_copy, "FETCHING BACKGROUND...PLEASE WAIT", (80, 400), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (0,0,255), 2)
    
    else: 
        # segmenting the hand region
        hand = segment_hand(gray_frame)
        

        # Checking if we are able to detect the hand...
        if hand is not None:
            
            thresholded, hand_segment = hand

            # Drawing contours around hand segment
            cv2.drawContours(frame_copy, [hand_segment + (ROI_right, ROI_top)], -1, (255, 0, 0),1)
            
            cv2.imshow("Thesholded Hand Image", thresholded)
            
            thresholded = cv2.resize(thresholded, (64, 64))
            thresholded = cv2.cvtColor(thresholded, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
            thresholded = np.reshape(thresholded, (1,thresholded.shape[0],thresholded.shape[1],3))
            
            pred = model.predict(thresholded)
            cv2.putText(frame_copy, word_dict[np.argmax(pred)], (170, 45), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,0,255), 2)
            
    # Draw ROI on frame_copy
    cv2.rectangle(frame_copy, (ROI_left, ROI_top), (ROI_right, ROI_bottom), (255,128,0), 3)

    # incrementing the number of frames for tracking
    num_frames += 1

    # Display the frame with segmented hand
    cv2.putText(frame_copy, "DataFlair hand sign recognition_ _ _", (10, 20), cv2.FONT_ITALIC, 0.5, (51,255,51), 1)
    cv2.imshow("Sign Detection", frame_copy)
    # Close windows with Esc
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the code for predicting the hand gesture but camera is not opening. The code is running continuously but not showing any error.
Please anyone reslove this issue. This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:
I am getting this in anaconda prompt

Comment: Hi @Lokesh Kumar, Welcome to SO, I recommend, you break down the code into smaller segments to identify which code segment is continuously running. I see you have an infinite while loop, so it is expected that the code will run infinitely.

Comment: As step 1, remove the infinite while loop, check if the image is getting retrieved properly from the camera, you will need to execute the command `ret,frame = cam.read()` in your code for that. Check if `frame` contains the image (numpy array).

Comment: I removed the while loop and this part is running 
      ret,frame = cam.read()
    # filpping the frame to prevent inverted image of captured frame...
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    frame_copy = frame.copy()

    # ROI from the frame
    roi = frame[ROI_top:ROI_bottom, ROI_right:ROI_left]
    gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray_frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_frame, (9, 9), 0)

Comment: But after this part when i running next part new window is opening and its showing sign detection not responding. Can u tell me what the further changes i need to do in code